# Remove cacheable="false" form Block in Layout file

Tags: magento2, layout, block-cache

In my multiple layout file has many block which have **cacheable="false"** attribute

```
<block class="Block\Class" name="blockname" cacheable="false" />
```

if **cacheable="false"** is not add there have many problems rise like current customer data not get, i update data but show only last added data, all data come from cache not new data come, etc.

so what is alternative way ?

Comment: You can get data using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Before removing `cacheable="false"`, you have to look at the template files and refactor them to use knockout.js.

There's a lot of tutorials out there. Also, if you look at the core-code, you can find usages in the minicart or welcome-message.